# OpenStreetMap OpenLayers в проекте require.js

Tags: карты, openstreetmap, openlayers, requirejs

Мне нужно подключить в проект OpenStreetMap с помощью библиотеки OpenLayers.
Вот, что у меня уже написано.
Файл index.jsp, в котором все нужные подключения:

```
<%@page import="java.util.Date"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<%
    String fa = "6.4.2";
    String bs = "5.3.1";

    String app_version = "0.0.1";
%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <!--link rel="icon" href="favicon64.png?name=oemz" type="image/x-icon">
        <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon64.png?name=oemz" type="image/x-icon"-->

        <title>Welcome</title>

        <link href="lib/fontawesome/<%= fa%>/css/fontawesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="lib/fontawesome/<%= fa%>/css/brands.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="lib/fontawesome/<%= fa%>/css/solid.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="lib/fontawesome/<%= fa%>/css/regular.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="lib/bootstrap/<%= bs%>/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="lib/osm/ol.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="common/style/main.css?nc=<%= app_version%>" rel="stylesheet">

        <script src="lib/requirejs/require-2.3.6.min.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <script>
            "use strict";

            require.config({
                // The shim config allows us to configure dependencies for
                // scripts that do not call define() to register a module
                shim: {
                    underscore: {exports: "_"},
                    bootstrap: {deps: ["jquery"]},
                    backbone: {
                        deps: [
                            "underscore",
                            "jquery"
                        ],
                        exports: "Backbone"
                    }
                },
                paths: {
                    jquery: "lib/jquery/jquery-3.7.1.min",
                    underscore: "lib/underscore/underscore-umd-1.13.6.min",
                    backbone: "lib/backbone/backbone-1.5.0.min",
                    bootstrap: "lib/bootstrap/5.3.1/js/bootstrap.bundle.min",
                    text: "lib/requirejs/text-2.0.16.min",
                    ol: "lib/osm/ol",

                    modules: "app/modules"
                },
                urlArgs: function (id, url) {
                    var nc = "nc=<%= app_version%>";
                    ;
                    if (url.indexOf("./lib/") !== -1) {
                        nc = "";
                    }

                    return nc == "" ? "" : ((url.indexOf("?") === -1 ? "?" : "&") + nc);
                }
            });

            require(["jquery", "backbone", "app/router", "app/app"],
                    function ($, Backbone, Router, App) {
                        new App({el: "body"}).render();

                        new Router({$container: $("main")});
                        Backbone.history.start();
                    });
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

map-view.html:

```
<h1>Карта</h1>
<div id="mapContainer" class = "p-5 mb-4 bg-body-tertiary rounded-3"></div>
```

map-view.js:

```
define(["jquery", "backbone", "text!modules/map/map-view.html",  "ol", "bootstrap"],
        function ($, Backbone, html, ol) {
            "use strict";
            let Clazz = Backbone.View.extend({
                $container: null,
                initialize: function (p) {
                    p = p || {};
                    this.$container = p.$container || this.$container;
                },
                render: function () {
                    this.$el.html(html);
                    this.initMap();
                    return this;
                },

                initMap: function () {
//                   Создаем экземпляр объекта Map для загрузки карты
                    var map = new ol.Map({
                        target: 'mapContainer', // Идентификатор div контейнера карты
                        // Устанавливаем для загрузки слоя в контейнер карты
                        layers: [
                            // Загружаем тайловый слой
                            new ol.Tile({
                                // Источник данных, соответствующий слою, здесь для загрузки данных онлайн-сервиса листов OpenStreetMap
                                source: new ol.OSM()
                            })
                        ],
                        // Настройки просмотра карты
                        view: new ol.View({
                            center: [32, 113], // Начальный центр отображения карты
                            zoom: 2 // Начальный уровень отображения карты
                        })
                    });
                },
                load: function () {
                    let defer = $.Deferred();
                    this.render();
                    this.$container.html(this.$el);
                    defer.resolve();
                    return defer.promise();
                },
                clear: function () {
                    this.remove();
                }
            });
            return Clazz;
        });
```

файлы ol.css, ol.js и ol.js.map взяты отсюда https://openlayers.org/download/

При запуске на странице карта не появляется, а в консоли вот такая ошибка:

```
map-view.js?nc=0.0.1:26 Uncaught TypeError: ol.OSM is not a constructor
    at r.initMap (map-view.js?nc=0.0.1:26:17)
    at r.render (map-view.js?nc=0.0.1:13:11)
    at r.load (map-view.js?nc=0.0.1:133:11)
    at router.js?nc=0.0.1:47:18
    at Object.execCb (require-2.3.6.min.js:5:16727)
    at e.check (require-2.3.6.min.js:5:10499)
    at e.<anonymous> (require-2.3.6.min.js:5:12915)
    at require-2.3.6.min.js:5:1542
    at require-2.3.6.min.js:5:13376
    at each (require-2.3.6.min.js:5:1020)
```

Вместо ol.OSM пробовала ol.source.OSM, тогда другая ошибка

```
map-view.js?nc=0.0.1:26 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'OSM')
    at r.initMap (map-view.js?nc=0.0.1:26:31)
    at r.render (map-view.js?nc=0.0.1:13:11)
    at r.load (map-view.js?nc=0.0.1:133:11)
    at router.js?nc=0.0.1:47:18
    at Object.execCb (require-2.3.6.min.js:5:16727)
    at e.check (require-2.3.6.min.js:5:10499)
    at e.<anonymous> (require-2.3.6.min.js:5:12915)
    at require-2.3.6.min.js:5:1542
    at require-2.3.6.min.js:5:13376
    at each (require-2.3.6.min.js:5:1020)
```